# VBA Opening a file with a given destination

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function in a macro that allows me to select a file using inputbox, or is it possible to always start showing files at the same time, so that I don't have to look in folders. For example, when the selectFile window appears, the folder should be \banksl\dfs\BH\BPR\

```
strPath1 = selectFile
If strPath1 = "" Then Exit Function
Set bilans = Workbooks.Open(strPath1, False, True)
Private Function selectFile1()
Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fd
.InitialFileName = ActiveWorkbook.path
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.Filters.Clear
.Filters.Add "Excel", "*.xlsm"

If .Show = True Then selectFile = .SelectedItems(1)

End With
```

Comment: Did you write this code? That's exactly what `.InitialFileName` is doing... Just change what it is equal to...

Comment: @Toddleson Im learning VBA, but for many things im using ready-made solutions